# sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server

Tags: sudo

Every time I try to use `sudo` I get this:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server
```

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
FF02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`/etc/hostname` has:

```
ubuntu-server
```

I think there is some other setting that causes the `unable to resole host` error, but I cannot find these.

Comment: Compare content of your /etc/hostname with the second line of /etc/hosts. Are there any special characters not printed out?

Answer (score 5):

This may mean your DNS lookups are broken.

Your /etc/hosts file looks fine.   You want it too look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-server
```

But there are several legitimate variants.

Make sure you have a matching hostname in /etc/hostname .

Check /etc/resolv.conf to see if you have working name servers defined.

See if you can resolve any hostnames.  Does `nslookup google.com` work ? 
If not, your DNS lookup is failing, either due to configuration or a network or firewall problem (possibly at a point beyond what you have control of with your server).

In my experience, `sudo` will eventually ask you for you password, and grant you elevated privileges,  after domain lookup times out.

Try manually adding the correct DNS name servers to /etc/resolv.conf.

In a pinch, you can use public servers.  Here's what the file looks like using Google DNS servers:

```
/etc# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `/etc/hosts`, you have a typo `127.0.1.1` is not loopback, change it to `127.0.0.1`, save and reboot.

Comment: This is the default configuration with Vagrant precise32. It uses `127.0.1.1` on that line... are you sure this is wrong? It was working fine until I tried changing my hostname away from the default.

Comment: -1 This answer is incorrect.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rescue/+bug/19553/comments/9 kind of explains this.  127.0.1.1 is a common placeholder for when you don't want to, or cannot, use 127.0.0.1.  They both ultimately resolve to the local loopback interface (as does anything in the 127.0.0.0/8 reserved netblock).