# hadoopmaster is not in the sudoers file

Tags: sudo

When I wanted to execute

```
hadoopmaster@dhruvhadoop3-HP-Compaq-dc5800-Small-Form-Factor:~$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

It gave me the following error

```
sudo: unable to resolve host dhruvhadoop3-HP-Compaq-dc5800-Small-Form-Factor
[sudo] password for hadoopmaster:
hadoopmaster is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: You should use `gksudo` and friends to run graphical applications as super-user. See [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](/q/11760/175814)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Isn't `pkexec` the replacement for `gksudo`.

Comment: @Marton: That works too.

Answer (score 0):

Its about the `/etc/sudoers`.If you simply want have sudo access then add you user to the group `sudo` via `usermod -aG sudo username`. This will add the group `sudo` to the user `username` (Keep in mind that you need `root` access to execute `usermod`). For more information look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Your second error message indicates that there is anything wrong with your hostname (Click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357155/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-ubuntu-server) for help. And you should not need root access to edit `~/.bashrc`.