# sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1kaushal

Tags: sudo, hostname

Yes, Might be duplicate of following links 
Tried both links solutions but didn't worked for me.

1. [Error message when I run sudo: unable to resolve host (none)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)
2. [sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357155/sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-ubuntu-server)

Following is my `/etc/hosts` output:

```
127.0.0.1 kaushal
120.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Following is my `/etc/hostname` output:

```
127.0.0.1 kaushal
120.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.com
```

Every time when I write command `sudo apt-get update` I get following error message.

```
sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1kaushal
```

Also in my terminal I get `kaushal@127:~$` as following screenshot.
[image]

It was not like that before.

All this started happening after I change my username from

```
All Setting >  Details > Device name
```

Any suggestion what's wrong with my machine??
How can I resolve this problem.
Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the line  `127.0.0.1 localhost.com` , save changes and then reboot your machine?

Comment: Also try to interchange the lines such like : `127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost` comes first then `127.0.1.1    kaushal`  where `kaushal` is your machine name.

Comment: Yes I did that too.

Comment: Suthar there's a typo in **127.0.0.1 kaushal**...it's supposed to be **127.0.1.1 kaushal**

Comment: Maybe, I've checked my hostname file and now it has only my name. There is nothing like "127.0.0.1 kaushal" so I guess that was the problem.

Comment: @Suthar Did that solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't try this one "127.0.1.1 kaushal ", Check my update in question.

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question. Instead, edit the solution out of your question and put it in the answer space. You can then accept your own answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter (much) if the short name is associated with 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 -- the latter is a Debian/Ubuntu specific thing, where the hostname configured in the installer is added to /etc/hosts. In the good old days there was only a single entry, listing the hostname first and localhost second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to 
 **All Setting >  Details > Device Name** 
  changed the device name to **kaushal**
Just make sure that your **/etc/hostname** file has only your machine name.For my case it was `kaushal`

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question specifically
In your `/etc/hosts` for `localhost` change `127.0.0.1  kaushal` to
 `127.0.1.1 localhost localhost.localdomain  kaushal`